# Outline for argument paper

Tags: outline

I am doing an argument essay on a quote that I agree with which is about being yourself, and the quote is from Ralph Waldo Emerson.  I am having trouble getting started.  We are to use the ethos, pathos, logos method of persuasive writing.  Have any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, my recommendation would be that you read up on what the ethos, pathos, and logos are and then attempt your essay. You will get feedback from your teacher and can then incorporate that feedback into your next essay. Eventually, with enough essays written (the rule says that you need to invest 10,000 hours) you may become a master.

The secret to writing, in other words, is to write. You don't need better understanding but more practice. To write a good essay, you need to have written many bad essays. So get off the internet and write.